# Salesforce Packaging Bug with Lightning Components? (Warning: very strange!)

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, unit-test, tooling-api, unmanaged-package

Since years I'm using Metadata and Tooling Apex classes to connect with those APIs (based on Andrew Fawcetts work here https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi). Today I'm encountering a very strange issue in form of an package upload error which I can not understand. The issue seems totally wired and without any logical connection...

In hours of work, I was finally able to drill it down to just 3 easy things, 100% reproducible within minutes:

1. **ToolingAPI.cls** (http://www.elastify.org/ToolingAPI.cls) - set to API v36.0
2. **ToolingAPITest.cls** (http://www.elastify.org/ToolingAPITest.cls) - v36.0, too.
3. **One empty Lightning Component** (details below)

Due to size limits I could not save the post with all the code, so I put the classes on my homepage. These are older versions from around 2013, but still work flawlessly.

With just the two classes:

- you can run tests: they succeed with no problems.
- create a **new unmanaged package**
- add both classes to the package
- upload the package: no problems, tests succeed again.

Now let's add a blank component:

- create an new empty lightning component (only `<aura:component ></aura:component>`) with developer console.
- add that to the package
- and upload it: all good, it still works, no problem!

Finally we add a controller:

- create an **empty(!) JS controller** inside the lightning component (consisting just of `({})`).
- try to upload the package again ==> now the Apex tests are failing with

> **System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please
>   commit or rollback before calling out**
>
> Class.ToolingAPI.submitRestCall: line 2355, column 1, 
>   Class.ToolingAPI.submitRestCall: line 2317, column 1, 
>   Class.ToolingAPI.submitRestCall: line 2309, column 1, 
>   Class.ToolingAPI.query: line 132, column 1, 
>   Class.ToolingAPITest.testQueryApexClassMember: line 67, column 1

- running the test with Dev Console or at setup: no error!
- deleting just the empty controller, I can upload the package again, the error disappeared!
- API version of the compo seems irrelevant. I've tried v36.0 and v41.0, no differece.

I can't figure what can be wrong here. At this point, I can only think of a very strange salesforce error.

It must be related to callouts in conjunction with the existence of a lightning componets JS controller. Crazy! I have another class wrapping the metadata-api based on https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi: **with that the same is happening**.

**Update 2017-10-16 - existing package-members immune**

I have older packages which contains lots of lightning compos with controllers already. Those I still can upload together with ToolingAPI with no issues - only new compos added are creating the error. However if you save the existing component they will start to produce that error, too. Luckily I got one disposable component to try this... So now I can't make any changes to all of my vital lightning components, or I will loose the ability to upload the package. Not nice!

**Update (2017-10-18) - possibly related with test.setMock()**

I think that it is related to the mockup tests. It looks like the `Test.setMock()` is not working (e.g. line 56 of `ToolingAPITest.cls`) and during the tests, **not the mockup**, but the **real callout** is invoked. And as a result it's failing.

As a workaround I'm trying to hack some `test.isRunningTest()` into the code and trying to return null instead something "meaningful". Also I have to wipe all `System.assert...()` to make this fly. But this hack is total crap, plus messing up the code, plus it will degrade my coverage. Bottom-line: this workaround is not OK, but I have to upload this package with a lot of time-pressure - no matter what.

**For a real solution I'm out of ideas. Totally.**

Unfortunately I have no premier support and Salesforce will shut my ticket down in the support immediately.

[image]

Comment: That is very odd, but you are right - I tried your classes with a test package I keep handy and get the same result. Remove the JS, and it uploads. Let me raise with Premier Support and see what they have to say...

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC thank you so much, I highly appreciate your help on this!

Comment: Quick update - Support has been able to re-create it in their Winter 18 Sandboxes, so it is looking like a bug right now...will let you know if they create a KI

Comment: I just hit this issue in another packaging org. But when I wrapped the code in the test that invokes the callout between a test.StartTest/StopTest, I was then able to upload the package...so might be worth trying that. Support is supposed to get back to me tomorrow with an update.

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC thank you so much for all your feedback!! `test.startTest()` and `test.stopTest()` are doing the magic and it WORKS! And the best is, that the coverage stays exactly as it was before without that start/stop. So why don't you answer this question with that workaround? And provide the final feedback from the support into that answer, too. I will accept this as solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to replicate this issue in two packages, so have raised it with support, and they are currently researching it (they were able to re-create it)

One thing I noticed as a workaround - I had many classes with mock callouts, both Web Service and HTTP. But only some failed - and they both did NOT make use of Start/Stop Test.

So even though they worked fine in regular test runs, once I updated my tests to invoke the code that invokes the callouts like below, I could then upload the package.

```
Test.StartTest() 
    //Invoke code that makes callout
Test.Stop Test()
```

Answer (score 2):

For reference and tracking, here is the known issue:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EO8L