# Tests fail (only) during upload with "CalloutException ..uncommitted work pending"

Tags: metadata-api, callout, tooling-api, platform-bug, winter18

This must have its root cause in a **Winter '18 change/bug** as this worked before for years.

When uploading a big (takes a while to upload) managed packaged that contains [Apex Tooling API - REST edition](https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi/tree/apex-toolingapi-rest) and [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) the upload fails with:

> System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please
>   commit or rollback before calling out

...in many and not always the same tests:

[image]

(Note: Also created issue at https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/issues/189)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a new salesforce bug that happend to me after W18 rollout, too. Thanks to @BritishBoyinDC, there is a workaround which is working for me:

[Salesforce Packaging Bug with Lightning Components? (Warning: very strange!)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/195625/salesforce-packaging-bug-with-lightning-components-warning-very-strange)

The gist of it is: Modify the test-class so that the code that invokes the callouts is wrapped like this

```
Test.StartTest() 
    // Invoke code that makes callout
Test.Stop Test()
```

The coverage will not go down but stay exactly as it was. My MetadataService.cls is still 100% covered and all package uploads are succeeding again as before W18.

Comment: It worked. @BritishBoyinDC and you saved my weekend. I owe you both a  beer.